# I Implemented sklearn's Lasso in tensorflow but not having the same results

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have a model implemented in Scikit-learn that is based on `Lasso`.
Here is the code

```
# Initiaze the hyperparameters for each dictionary
param1 = {}
param1['classifier'] = [LinearRegression()]

param2 = {}
param2['classifier__alpha'] = [0.1, 0.5, 1]
param2['classifier'] = [Ridge()]

param3 = {}
param3['classifier__alpha'] = [0.1, 0.5, 1]
param3['classifier'] = [Lasso()]

param4 = {}
param4['classifier__n_neighbors'] = [2,5,10,25,50]
param4['classifier'] = [KNeighborsRegressor()]

pipeline = pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("scaler", CustomScaler(MEAN,STD)),
                       ("flatten", FlattenTransformer()),
                       ("classifier", LinearRegression())])
params = [param1, param2, param3, param4] # param5

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, params, cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error').fit(train_images,train_biomasses)

grid_search.best_params_
# {'classifier': Lasso(alpha=0.1), 'classifier__alpha': 0.1}
```

Here is the code I wrote

```py
from functools import partial

def build_model():
    # RegularizedDense = partial(
    #     tf.keras.layers.Dense,
    #     activation="relu",
    #     kernel_initializer="he_normal",
    #     kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(1.0)
    # )
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(2700,), name="inputs"),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.1))
    ])
    
    return model

def exponential_decay(lr0, s):
    def exponential_decay_fn(epoch):
        return lr0 * 0.1 ** (epoch/s)
    return exponential_decay_fn

def build_optimizer(learning_rate=1e-4, decay=None):
    # optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    return optimizer

def build_losses_metrics():
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    
    train_rmse_metric = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()
    val_rmse_metric = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()
    
    return (loss_fn, (train_rmse_metric, val_rmse_metric))
    
def build_datasets(batch_size=32):
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_biomasses))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(512).batch(batch_size)

    validate_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validate_images, validate_biomasses))
    validate_dataset = validate_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    return train_dataset, validate_dataset
    
def train(
    model,
    optimizer,
    train_dataset, validation_dataset,
    epochs=50,
    lr=1e-3,
    lr_decay=False,
    lr_step=10
):
    loss_fn, (train_rmse_metric, val_rmse_metric) = build_losses_metrics()
    
    train_losses = []
    val_losses = []
    learning_rate_decay_fn = exponential_decay(lr, lr_step)
    current_lr = lr

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        
        if lr_decay:
            learning_rate = learning_rate_decay_fn(epoch)
            optimizer.learning_rate.assign(learning_rate)

        loss_epoch = 0.
        for batch, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                y_ = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
                loss_batch = loss_fn(y_batch_train, y_)

                loss_epoch += loss_batch

            grads = tape.gradient(loss_batch, model.trainable_weights)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

        train_losses.append(tf.math.reduce_mean(loss_epoch))

        val_loss_epoch = 0.
        for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in validation_dataset:
            val_y_ = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
            val_loss_batch = loss_fn(y_batch_val, val_y_)

            val_loss_epoch += val_loss_batch

        val_losses.append(tf.math.reduce_mean(val_loss_epoch))
        
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: loss: {train_losses[-1]} - val_loss: {val_losses[-1]}")
    return train_losses, val_losses
        
def run(epochs=50, learning_rate=1e-4, decay=1e-4):
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    np.random.seed(1992)
    tf.random.set_seed(1992)
    
    model = build_model()
    
    optimizer = build_optimizer(learning_rate, decay=decay)
    train_dataset, validation_dataset = build_datasets(batch_size=32)
    
    return train(model=model,
                 optimizer=optimizer,
                 train_dataset=train_dataset,
                 validation_dataset=validation_dataset,
                 lr=learning_rate,
                 epochs=epochs)

epochs = 400
learning_rate=1e-3
train_losses, validation_losses = run(epochs=epochs, learning_rate=learning_rate)
```

Here is the result of the execution

```
Epoch 0: loss: 847.075927734375 - val_loss: 158.7601776123047
Epoch 1: loss: 584.6080322265625 - val_loss: 159.98387145996094
Epoch 2: loss: 566.870361328125 - val_loss: 116.31696319580078
Epoch 3: loss: 563.249267578125 - val_loss: 120.13416290283203
Epoch 4: loss: 551.9866333007812 - val_loss: 106.21666717529297
Epoch 5: loss: 545.043701171875 - val_loss: 106.00625610351562
Epoch 6: loss: 556.5231323242188 - val_loss: 139.84605407714844
Epoch 7: loss: 563.5502319335938 - val_loss: 119.96963500976562
Epoch 8: loss: 547.5770874023438 - val_loss: 138.95558166503906
Epoch 9: loss: 547.4338989257812 - val_loss: 113.98006439208984
Epoch 10: loss: 542.088134765625 - val_loss: 108.67926788330078
Epoch 11: loss: 536.9991455078125 - val_loss: 111.34986877441406
Epoch 12: loss: 539.1815795898438 - val_loss: 106.76664733886719
Epoch 13: loss: 529.169677734375 - val_loss: 116.39300537109375
Epoch 14: loss: 549.8356323242188 - val_loss: 111.42301940917969
Epoch 15: loss: 531.5046997070312 - val_loss: 121.7109603881836
Epoch 16: loss: 532.90869140625 - val_loss: 110.92386627197266
Epoch 17: loss: 527.7339477539062 - val_loss: 131.94984436035156
Epoch 18: loss: 519.3847045898438 - val_loss: 137.0780487060547
Epoch 19: loss: 522.2667236328125 - val_loss: 114.2005615234375
Epoch 20: loss: 515.1701049804688 - val_loss: 104.97427368164062
Epoch 21: loss: 523.9987182617188 - val_loss: 111.52166748046875
Epoch 22: loss: 511.7991638183594 - val_loss: 107.33300018310547
Epoch 23: loss: 511.7978210449219 - val_loss: 106.44991302490234
Epoch 24: loss: 517.2681274414062 - val_loss: 116.37968444824219
Epoch 25: loss: 507.038330078125 - val_loss: 111.16574096679688
Epoch 26: loss: 507.4341735839844 - val_loss: 108.5770492553711
Epoch 27: loss: 492.9891662597656 - val_loss: 124.1153793334961
Epoch 28: loss: 503.1880187988281 - val_loss: 101.68212127685547
Epoch 29: loss: 509.0335388183594 - val_loss: 100.03245544433594
Epoch 30: loss: 503.455322265625 - val_loss: 100.5913314819336
Epoch 31: loss: 497.4955749511719 - val_loss: 127.98064422607422
Epoch 32: loss: 489.5680236816406 - val_loss: 102.95386505126953
Epoch 33: loss: 497.2449645996094 - val_loss: 114.24052429199219
Epoch 34: loss: 496.8539733886719 - val_loss: 108.60224914550781
Epoch 35: loss: 493.4102783203125 - val_loss: 99.18386840820312
Epoch 36: loss: 499.2474060058594 - val_loss: 107.8803939819336
Epoch 37: loss: 481.9783935546875 - val_loss: 108.40951538085938
Epoch 38: loss: 492.92291259765625 - val_loss: 103.66437530517578
Epoch 39: loss: 485.2967529296875 - val_loss: 104.97471618652344
Epoch 40: loss: 483.46575927734375 - val_loss: 115.77208709716797
Epoch 41: loss: 483.249755859375 - val_loss: 151.1378631591797
Epoch 42: loss: 488.1317138671875 - val_loss: 115.21915435791016
Epoch 43: loss: 483.76031494140625 - val_loss: 116.80110931396484
Epoch 44: loss: 487.7470397949219 - val_loss: 110.9793930053711
Epoch 45: loss: 481.63507080078125 - val_loss: 108.36771392822266
Epoch 46: loss: 482.9681701660156 - val_loss: 103.23908996582031
Epoch 47: loss: 477.44970703125 - val_loss: 106.9701156616211
Epoch 48: loss: 480.35711669921875 - val_loss: 109.85052490234375
Epoch 49: loss: 476.7109680175781 - val_loss: 107.3569107055664
Epoch 50: loss: 474.3595275878906 - val_loss: 105.09278869628906
Epoch 51: loss: 477.8955383300781 - val_loss: 99.09465026855469
Epoch 52: loss: 472.75164794921875 - val_loss: 105.4655532836914
Epoch 53: loss: 476.35858154296875 - val_loss: 110.5615005493164
Epoch 54: loss: 472.6387939453125 - val_loss: 102.34373474121094
Epoch 55: loss: 469.86981201171875 - val_loss: 101.6429214477539
Epoch 56: loss: 471.7933044433594 - val_loss: 99.83200073242188
Epoch 57: loss: 464.2228088378906 - val_loss: 100.06639862060547
Epoch 58: loss: 475.8570861816406 - val_loss: 100.1411361694336
Epoch 59: loss: 469.5304260253906 - val_loss: 106.68754577636719
Epoch 60: loss: 475.5203857421875 - val_loss: 100.88705444335938
Epoch 61: loss: 470.883544921875 - val_loss: 110.94203186035156
Epoch 62: loss: 467.8878479003906 - val_loss: 101.2822494506836
Epoch 63: loss: 466.05792236328125 - val_loss: 100.43091583251953
Epoch 64: loss: 467.42303466796875 - val_loss: 101.63124084472656
Epoch 65: loss: 467.1925048828125 - val_loss: 110.7307357788086
Epoch 66: loss: 467.52593994140625 - val_loss: 99.30562591552734
Epoch 67: loss: 463.7406921386719 - val_loss: 100.6451644897461
Epoch 68: loss: 465.1089782714844 - val_loss: 100.5382080078125
Epoch 69: loss: 465.9606628417969 - val_loss: 110.55416107177734
Epoch 70: loss: 463.6502990722656 - val_loss: 105.38463592529297
Epoch 71: loss: 463.7268371582031 - val_loss: 98.45337677001953
Epoch 72: loss: 468.327392578125 - val_loss: 102.80609893798828
Epoch 73: loss: 460.4519958496094 - val_loss: 104.26699829101562
Epoch 74: loss: 464.2290344238281 - val_loss: 98.02379608154297
Epoch 75: loss: 459.0707092285156 - val_loss: 110.16661071777344
Epoch 76: loss: 463.8221435546875 - val_loss: 102.0076904296875
Epoch 77: loss: 457.8291931152344 - val_loss: 97.28372192382812
Epoch 78: loss: 464.15667724609375 - val_loss: 105.54214477539062
Epoch 79: loss: 460.37872314453125 - val_loss: 97.70496368408203
Epoch 80: loss: 460.96063232421875 - val_loss: 102.3382568359375
Epoch 81: loss: 459.4374084472656 - val_loss: 97.27777862548828
Epoch 82: loss: 458.4649658203125 - val_loss: 98.91461944580078
Epoch 83: loss: 459.7217102050781 - val_loss: 99.78578186035156
Epoch 84: loss: 460.1854248046875 - val_loss: 97.59530639648438
Epoch 85: loss: 458.0945739746094 - val_loss: 98.57728576660156
Epoch 86: loss: 458.51641845703125 - val_loss: 102.36064147949219
Epoch 87: loss: 457.6965637207031 - val_loss: 98.78395080566406
Epoch 88: loss: 465.5695495605469 - val_loss: 105.8673324584961
Epoch 89: loss: 456.6957702636719 - val_loss: 99.67933654785156
Epoch 90: loss: 456.6771545410156 - val_loss: 98.16921997070312
Epoch 91: loss: 459.624755859375 - val_loss: 109.00318145751953
Epoch 92: loss: 455.58251953125 - val_loss: 98.51361846923828
Epoch 93: loss: 463.1281433105469 - val_loss: 97.90188598632812
Epoch 94: loss: 455.00921630859375 - val_loss: 99.96898651123047
Epoch 95: loss: 449.8885192871094 - val_loss: 96.98976135253906
Epoch 96: loss: 460.0137023925781 - val_loss: 96.2021255493164
Epoch 97: loss: 456.7822265625 - val_loss: 99.29813385009766
Epoch 98: loss: 456.98211669921875 - val_loss: 98.63404846191406
Epoch 99: loss: 453.4152526855469 - val_loss: 97.25257873535156
Epoch 100: loss: 454.2278747558594 - val_loss: 97.14910125732422
Epoch 101: loss: 453.0674133300781 - val_loss: 97.72257995605469
Epoch 102: loss: 457.1690979003906 - val_loss: 100.79244995117188
Epoch 103: loss: 457.0799255371094 - val_loss: 96.21158599853516
Epoch 104: loss: 450.21173095703125 - val_loss: 100.99701690673828
Epoch 105: loss: 452.1216125488281 - val_loss: 98.9791488647461
Epoch 106: loss: 452.4648132324219 - val_loss: 98.90581512451172
Epoch 107: loss: 454.3359069824219 - val_loss: 100.54856872558594
Epoch 108: loss: 457.5542297363281 - val_loss: 105.72451782226562
Epoch 109: loss: 453.9736328125 - val_loss: 97.04446411132812
Epoch 110: loss: 452.2619323730469 - val_loss: 97.46793365478516
Epoch 111: loss: 455.6089782714844 - val_loss: 100.0567855834961
Epoch 112: loss: 455.6871032714844 - val_loss: 99.18238830566406
Epoch 113: loss: 450.9131164550781 - val_loss: 98.396240234375
Epoch 114: loss: 451.55987548828125 - val_loss: 101.84715270996094
Epoch 115: loss: 455.97705078125 - val_loss: 99.65447998046875
Epoch 116: loss: 452.658935546875 - val_loss: 97.8386001586914
Epoch 117: loss: 451.8746643066406 - val_loss: 96.30899047851562
Epoch 118: loss: 454.3466796875 - val_loss: 106.23787689208984
Epoch 119: loss: 452.0690612792969 - val_loss: 99.08953857421875
Epoch 120: loss: 452.4654846191406 - val_loss: 97.02693176269531
Epoch 121: loss: 449.90234375 - val_loss: 97.01411437988281
Epoch 122: loss: 453.8165283203125 - val_loss: 100.29322052001953
Epoch 123: loss: 451.3995666503906 - val_loss: 96.72403717041016
Epoch 124: loss: 451.07806396484375 - val_loss: 101.33114624023438
Epoch 125: loss: 452.2001647949219 - val_loss: 96.57894134521484
Epoch 126: loss: 452.9191589355469 - val_loss: 98.23367309570312
Epoch 127: loss: 449.3941345214844 - val_loss: 99.61105346679688
Epoch 128: loss: 452.7442626953125 - val_loss: 98.24333953857422
Epoch 129: loss: 452.52923583984375 - val_loss: 98.70343780517578
Epoch 130: loss: 450.1275329589844 - val_loss: 96.91618347167969
Epoch 131: loss: 452.13299560546875 - val_loss: 95.6628189086914
Epoch 132: loss: 449.8660583496094 - val_loss: 97.2622299194336
Epoch 133: loss: 449.65887451171875 - val_loss: 97.45806884765625
Epoch 134: loss: 449.7442626953125 - val_loss: 96.74287414550781
Epoch 135: loss: 452.2209167480469 - val_loss: 96.0275650024414
Epoch 136: loss: 450.0367431640625 - val_loss: 98.23724365234375
Epoch 137: loss: 448.8655700683594 - val_loss: 98.300537109375
Epoch 138: loss: 451.7554016113281 - val_loss: 101.69792938232422
Epoch 139: loss: 454.3482971191406 - val_loss: 97.0973129272461
Epoch 140: loss: 451.4029235839844 - val_loss: 96.46884155273438
Epoch 141: loss: 450.0864562988281 - val_loss: 97.57160949707031
Epoch 142: loss: 452.6539611816406 - val_loss: 98.06654357910156
Epoch 143: loss: 452.9635009765625 - val_loss: 96.98999786376953
Epoch 144: loss: 449.375732421875 - val_loss: 97.08302307128906
Epoch 145: loss: 455.64300537109375 - val_loss: 98.29078674316406
Epoch 146: loss: 449.7545166015625 - val_loss: 97.31458282470703
Epoch 147: loss: 448.3454895019531 - val_loss: 97.41017150878906
Epoch 148: loss: 451.1374206542969 - val_loss: 96.47671508789062
Epoch 149: loss: 450.7874450683594 - val_loss: 95.87786102294922
Epoch 150: loss: 451.97589111328125 - val_loss: 95.6712646484375
Epoch 151: loss: 450.7940673828125 - val_loss: 99.03018951416016
Epoch 152: loss: 448.3888244628906 - val_loss: 96.31082153320312
Epoch 153: loss: 451.3653259277344 - val_loss: 96.55095672607422
Epoch 154: loss: 449.8733215332031 - val_loss: 97.61719512939453
Epoch 155: loss: 448.97149658203125 - val_loss: 95.97036743164062
Epoch 156: loss: 452.4737854003906 - val_loss: 97.90641021728516
Epoch 157: loss: 448.4120178222656 - val_loss: 97.59449005126953
Epoch 158: loss: 448.980712890625 - val_loss: 99.00843811035156
Epoch 159: loss: 449.7715148925781 - val_loss: 98.71858978271484
Epoch 160: loss: 450.5384521484375 - val_loss: 100.6188735961914
Epoch 161: loss: 451.2767639160156 - val_loss: 97.51863861083984
Epoch 162: loss: 449.3151550292969 - val_loss: 97.367919921875
Epoch 163: loss: 452.6103820800781 - val_loss: 97.79457092285156
Epoch 164: loss: 448.2057189941406 - val_loss: 96.92853546142578
Epoch 165: loss: 449.69683837890625 - val_loss: 96.72354888916016
Epoch 166: loss: 450.1744079589844 - val_loss: 96.32561492919922
Epoch 167: loss: 450.008056640625 - val_loss: 96.28145599365234
Epoch 168: loss: 451.03887939453125 - val_loss: 96.93020629882812
Epoch 169: loss: 449.4725646972656 - val_loss: 96.45865631103516
Epoch 170: loss: 450.4540100097656 - val_loss: 95.40909576416016
Epoch 171: loss: 450.4195251464844 - val_loss: 96.52227783203125
Epoch 172: loss: 450.5582275390625 - val_loss: 97.4793472290039
Epoch 173: loss: 449.9660949707031 - val_loss: 95.69512939453125
Epoch 174: loss: 446.5926818847656 - val_loss: 96.79833984375
Epoch 175: loss: 449.91522216796875 - val_loss: 95.8263168334961
Epoch 176: loss: 447.26873779296875 - val_loss: 98.99745178222656
Epoch 177: loss: 450.3222961425781 - val_loss: 96.22772216796875
Epoch 178: loss: 448.63177490234375 - val_loss: 98.7435531616211
Epoch 179: loss: 446.5481262207031 - val_loss: 97.00751495361328
Epoch 180: loss: 450.5780334472656 - val_loss: 97.88690948486328
Epoch 181: loss: 449.1116638183594 - val_loss: 97.2146987915039
Epoch 182: loss: 450.4496154785156 - val_loss: 96.44254302978516
Epoch 183: loss: 446.32012939453125 - val_loss: 99.34430694580078
Epoch 184: loss: 446.66485595703125 - val_loss: 96.51043701171875
Epoch 185: loss: 446.88909912109375 - val_loss: 97.46516418457031
Epoch 186: loss: 447.5033874511719 - val_loss: 96.38636779785156
Epoch 187: loss: 448.890625 - val_loss: 96.17085266113281
Epoch 188: loss: 448.4964904785156 - val_loss: 99.32489776611328
Epoch 189: loss: 449.4647521972656 - val_loss: 95.74967193603516
Epoch 190: loss: 450.39349365234375 - val_loss: 95.82449340820312
Epoch 191: loss: 448.1368713378906 - val_loss: 98.2160415649414
Epoch 192: loss: 450.2295227050781 - val_loss: 96.32608032226562
Epoch 193: loss: 446.3965759277344 - val_loss: 99.42900085449219
Epoch 194: loss: 449.540283203125 - val_loss: 96.3811264038086
Epoch 195: loss: 450.3630065917969 - val_loss: 96.3318099975586
Epoch 196: loss: 446.8701171875 - val_loss: 95.79061126708984
Epoch 197: loss: 449.6808776855469 - val_loss: 96.84124755859375
Epoch 198: loss: 448.4356384277344 - val_loss: 96.3101806640625
Epoch 199: loss: 448.7823791503906 - val_loss: 96.1176528930664
Epoch 200: loss: 449.4550476074219 - val_loss: 96.64998626708984
Epoch 201: loss: 450.10888671875 - val_loss: 95.34820556640625
Epoch 202: loss: 449.8490295410156 - val_loss: 95.7176742553711
Epoch 203: loss: 449.1422119140625 - val_loss: 96.12824249267578
Epoch 204: loss: 448.55694580078125 - val_loss: 97.94233703613281
Epoch 205: loss: 450.0185546875 - val_loss: 96.29656982421875
Epoch 206: loss: 448.07818603515625 - val_loss: 96.52961730957031
Epoch 207: loss: 447.2069091796875 - val_loss: 97.3646469116211
Epoch 208: loss: 448.92919921875 - val_loss: 95.40940856933594
Epoch 209: loss: 449.58251953125 - val_loss: 98.36994171142578
Epoch 210: loss: 452.70086669921875 - val_loss: 96.01040649414062
Epoch 211: loss: 449.98699951171875 - val_loss: 96.78478240966797
Epoch 212: loss: 449.91546630859375 - val_loss: 96.15846252441406
Epoch 213: loss: 450.1114807128906 - val_loss: 96.40387725830078
Epoch 214: loss: 449.07830810546875 - val_loss: 97.43226623535156
Epoch 215: loss: 449.9971008300781 - val_loss: 96.98865509033203
Epoch 216: loss: 449.01336669921875 - val_loss: 95.88896942138672
Epoch 217: loss: 449.2881774902344 - val_loss: 97.53218078613281
Epoch 218: loss: 448.5071716308594 - val_loss: 95.47907257080078
Epoch 219: loss: 447.61895751953125 - val_loss: 96.29920196533203
Epoch 220: loss: 449.47625732421875 - val_loss: 97.40425109863281
Epoch 221: loss: 448.6600036621094 - val_loss: 101.34588623046875
Epoch 222: loss: 449.4443054199219 - val_loss: 96.1139907836914
Epoch 223: loss: 448.8155517578125 - val_loss: 98.19176483154297
Epoch 224: loss: 448.0467834472656 - val_loss: 98.63390350341797
Epoch 225: loss: 449.181396484375 - val_loss: 96.06834411621094
Epoch 226: loss: 448.3404846191406 - val_loss: 98.01530456542969
Epoch 227: loss: 447.5462646484375 - val_loss: 95.62828826904297
Epoch 228: loss: 449.4240417480469 - val_loss: 95.88542175292969
Epoch 229: loss: 451.1175231933594 - val_loss: 96.28475189208984
Epoch 230: loss: 448.94256591796875 - val_loss: 96.25310516357422
Epoch 231: loss: 449.68048095703125 - val_loss: 97.33654022216797
Epoch 232: loss: 448.2848815917969 - val_loss: 96.2500228881836
Epoch 233: loss: 449.83624267578125 - val_loss: 96.42926025390625
Epoch 234: loss: 449.0020751953125 - val_loss: 95.73167419433594
Epoch 235: loss: 448.7664489746094 - val_loss: 97.0711898803711
Epoch 236: loss: 446.8410949707031 - val_loss: 95.59280395507812
Epoch 237: loss: 448.98236083984375 - val_loss: 95.69206237792969
Epoch 238: loss: 450.6343994140625 - val_loss: 98.03248596191406
Epoch 239: loss: 448.12982177734375 - val_loss: 96.1108169555664
Epoch 240: loss: 449.7079772949219 - val_loss: 98.2567138671875
Epoch 241: loss: 447.1879577636719 - val_loss: 96.62137603759766
Epoch 242: loss: 447.3613586425781 - val_loss: 96.51026153564453
Epoch 243: loss: 448.68011474609375 - val_loss: 98.67510986328125
Epoch 244: loss: 450.47894287109375 - val_loss: 96.25545501708984
Epoch 245: loss: 445.7900390625 - val_loss: 95.72764587402344
Epoch 246: loss: 446.232421875 - val_loss: 95.74934387207031
Epoch 247: loss: 448.12860107421875 - val_loss: 97.63236999511719
Epoch 248: loss: 448.5235595703125 - val_loss: 95.3633804321289
Epoch 249: loss: 447.5834045410156 - val_loss: 99.32067108154297
Epoch 250: loss: 447.3578186035156 - val_loss: 98.52676391601562
Epoch 251: loss: 448.1993103027344 - val_loss: 97.82453918457031
Epoch 252: loss: 447.4939880371094 - val_loss: 95.96961212158203
Epoch 253: loss: 445.65338134765625 - val_loss: 97.19148254394531
Epoch 254: loss: 448.2876892089844 - val_loss: 95.78370666503906
Epoch 255: loss: 448.3876647949219 - val_loss: 100.29200744628906
Epoch 256: loss: 451.384521484375 - val_loss: 95.96392059326172
Epoch 257: loss: 448.0782470703125 - val_loss: 95.96009826660156
Epoch 258: loss: 447.6029052734375 - val_loss: 97.1167984008789
Epoch 259: loss: 449.1065368652344 - val_loss: 99.19495391845703
Epoch 260: loss: 448.4313659667969 - val_loss: 95.46548461914062
Epoch 261: loss: 447.4554748535156 - val_loss: 96.4761734008789
Epoch 262: loss: 448.15673828125 - val_loss: 96.36026000976562
Epoch 263: loss: 447.81134033203125 - val_loss: 97.19379425048828
Epoch 264: loss: 447.1545104980469 - val_loss: 95.80008697509766
Epoch 265: loss: 448.50030517578125 - val_loss: 96.77977752685547
Epoch 266: loss: 447.1940002441406 - val_loss: 99.17420959472656
Epoch 267: loss: 447.97357177734375 - val_loss: 97.48926544189453
Epoch 268: loss: 448.6673583984375 - val_loss: 95.76939392089844
Epoch 269: loss: 448.72479248046875 - val_loss: 96.87129211425781
Epoch 270: loss: 448.6628723144531 - val_loss: 96.73013305664062
Epoch 271: loss: 448.1092224121094 - val_loss: 96.96997833251953
Epoch 272: loss: 450.6113586425781 - val_loss: 99.54457092285156
Epoch 273: loss: 447.33380126953125 - val_loss: 96.0779800415039
Epoch 274: loss: 448.7845458984375 - val_loss: 96.4703140258789
Epoch 275: loss: 448.4481506347656 - val_loss: 96.36518859863281
Epoch 276: loss: 449.53863525390625 - val_loss: 96.36363220214844
Epoch 277: loss: 449.01904296875 - val_loss: 95.36627197265625
Epoch 278: loss: 448.4521179199219 - val_loss: 96.10830688476562
Epoch 279: loss: 448.6177673339844 - val_loss: 96.2638931274414
Epoch 280: loss: 447.91741943359375 - val_loss: 96.5622787475586
Epoch 281: loss: 447.18426513671875 - val_loss: 96.10635375976562
Epoch 282: loss: 450.2124328613281 - val_loss: 95.98343658447266
Epoch 283: loss: 445.8919982910156 - val_loss: 96.40095520019531
Epoch 284: loss: 448.9225158691406 - val_loss: 99.08332061767578
Epoch 285: loss: 451.8327331542969 - val_loss: 96.44686126708984
Epoch 286: loss: 450.9258117675781 - val_loss: 96.49341583251953
Epoch 287: loss: 449.3422546386719 - val_loss: 96.29725646972656
Epoch 288: loss: 445.6938171386719 - val_loss: 98.02930450439453
Epoch 289: loss: 445.10467529296875 - val_loss: 95.53852844238281
Epoch 290: loss: 447.1038818359375 - val_loss: 97.08586120605469
Epoch 291: loss: 449.4007568359375 - val_loss: 96.09859466552734
Epoch 292: loss: 447.41497802734375 - val_loss: 96.6626205444336
Epoch 293: loss: 448.1705627441406 - val_loss: 96.74125671386719
Epoch 294: loss: 448.3666076660156 - val_loss: 97.35401153564453
Epoch 295: loss: 450.4263610839844 - val_loss: 95.55182647705078
Epoch 296: loss: 446.4584655761719 - val_loss: 96.44827270507812
Epoch 297: loss: 448.71038818359375 - val_loss: 97.3622055053711
Epoch 298: loss: 450.2142028808594 - val_loss: 96.57585144042969
Epoch 299: loss: 447.4092102050781 - val_loss: 99.58077239990234
Epoch 300: loss: 447.806884765625 - val_loss: 101.20033264160156
Epoch 301: loss: 449.25482177734375 - val_loss: 96.4958724975586
Epoch 302: loss: 446.1800537109375 - val_loss: 96.3758316040039
Epoch 303: loss: 447.6533508300781 - val_loss: 97.42721557617188
Epoch 304: loss: 447.7839660644531 - val_loss: 96.5372543334961
Epoch 305: loss: 447.0205078125 - val_loss: 97.30355072021484
Epoch 306: loss: 447.7018127441406 - val_loss: 96.26265716552734
Epoch 307: loss: 446.2525939941406 - val_loss: 95.49018859863281
Epoch 308: loss: 449.7401123046875 - val_loss: 95.94829559326172
Epoch 309: loss: 450.55377197265625 - val_loss: 95.80023193359375
Epoch 340: loss: 447.4643249511719 - val_loss: 97.12619018554688
Epoch 341: loss: 449.16058349609375 - val_loss: 96.62779235839844
Epoch 342: loss: 448.22314453125 - val_loss: 96.62793731689453
Epoch 347: loss: 448.8013610839844 - val_loss: 95.95989227294922
Epoch 348: loss: 448.94854736328125 - val_loss: 97.42015075683594
Epoch 349: loss: 449.9473876953125 - val_loss: 98.4897689819336
Epoch 350: loss: 449.37835693359375 - val_loss: 95.75738525390625
Epoch 351: loss: 448.22723388671875 - val_loss: 95.62594604492188
Epoch 352: loss: 448.29669189453125 - val_loss: 96.71765899658203
Epoch 353: loss: 449.94085693359375 - val_loss: 96.61383056640625
Epoch 354: loss: 449.84027099609375 - val_loss: 95.7657699584961
Epoch 355: loss: 447.8819885253906 - val_loss: 95.76840209960938
Epoch 356: loss: 447.8974609375 - val_loss: 95.89303588867188
Epoch 357: loss: 447.2488708496094 - val_loss: 96.25495147705078
Epoch 358: loss: 446.8042907714844 - val_loss: 95.79498291015625
Epoch 359: loss: 449.310302734375 - val_loss: 97.06275939941406
Epoch 360: loss: 447.7292785644531 - val_loss: 96.94458770751953
Epoch 361: loss: 450.7572326660156 - val_loss: 96.6223373413086
Epoch 362: loss: 448.0852966308594 - val_loss: 97.0022201538086
Epoch 363: loss: 447.17364501953125 - val_loss: 95.81920623779297
Epoch 364: loss: 448.5683898925781 - val_loss: 96.20494079589844
Epoch 365: loss: 447.81427001953125 - val_loss: 96.55271911621094
Epoch 366: loss: 448.688720703125 - val_loss: 95.55145263671875
Epoch 367: loss: 448.43988037109375 - val_loss: 97.6124038696289
Epoch 368: loss: 447.0206298828125 - val_loss: 95.83692932128906
Epoch 369: loss: 448.39703369140625 - val_loss: 98.09520721435547
Epoch 370: loss: 448.4558410644531 - val_loss: 95.79071807861328
Epoch 371: loss: 449.0579833984375 - val_loss: 95.97594451904297
Epoch 372: loss: 449.515869140625 - val_loss: 95.78282165527344
Epoch 373: loss: 448.605224609375 - val_loss: 96.56583404541016
Epoch 374: loss: 449.01422119140625 - val_loss: 95.94359588623047
Epoch 375: loss: 446.36358642578125 - val_loss: 96.34536743164062
Epoch 376: loss: 447.9954833984375 - val_loss: 97.00811767578125
Epoch 377: loss: 446.4378356933594 - val_loss: 97.61347961425781
Epoch 378: loss: 448.4219970703125 - val_loss: 96.28117370605469
Epoch 379: loss: 448.88427734375 - val_loss: 96.4834976196289
Epoch 380: loss: 447.9678955078125 - val_loss: 95.76192474365234
Epoch 381: loss: 447.5173645019531 - val_loss: 95.57508850097656
Epoch 382: loss: 450.2215881347656 - val_loss: 95.90723419189453
Epoch 383: loss: 446.4511413574219 - val_loss: 96.56519317626953
Epoch 384: loss: 448.1116027832031 - val_loss: 95.84264373779297
Epoch 385: loss: 446.3388977050781 - val_loss: 97.37928771972656
Epoch 386: loss: 446.2598876953125 - val_loss: 97.44355773925781
Epoch 387: loss: 448.97418212890625 - val_loss: 95.93624114990234
Epoch 388: loss: 448.1927490234375 - val_loss: 95.74329376220703
Epoch 389: loss: 449.95098876953125 - val_loss: 97.33592224121094
Epoch 390: loss: 448.2254333496094 - val_loss: 96.584228515625
Epoch 391: loss: 448.4384460449219 - val_loss: 96.26628875732422
Epoch 392: loss: 450.11444091796875 - val_loss: 95.92509460449219
Epoch 393: loss: 447.34954833984375 - val_loss: 95.9112319946289
Epoch 394: loss: 450.5757751464844 - val_loss: 96.1070785522461
Epoch 395: loss: 449.10260009765625 - val_loss: 96.11609649658203
Epoch 396: loss: 446.2992248535156 - val_loss: 95.81678009033203
Epoch 397: loss: 448.07379150390625 - val_loss: 98.16239929199219
Epoch 398: loss: 447.3256530761719 - val_loss: 98.20945739746094
Epoch 399: loss: 447.22650146484375 - val_loss: 96.81021118164062
```

Here are the charts
[image: Losses vs Epochs]
[image]

The issue I have is that the validation has never been below **94**.
I don't know how to reduce it.

Please, any clue to reduce the validation loss?

Comment: I would just standardize the data, not using a BN layer for that... BN have more problems that normal standardization, as it keeps a running average of the parameters

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Unfortunately, removing BN and using only normal standardization makes the validation loss stagnates around 114 whereas with BN it stagnates around 94.